# Deploying Lambda Service Failing Because Domain Missing in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I’ll just prefix this question with I am very new to working within AWS Serverless having previously worked with Azure. So there is a fair chance I am missing something obvious here, but here goes…

I am currently trying to deploy my lambda service to AWS, and when I run ‘sls deploy --stage dev’ I get to the point where it starts to package the service but then falls over giving the error:

> Error: Could not set up basepath mapping. Try running sls
>   create_domain first. Error: Error: ‘dev-api.mywebsite.com’ could not
>   be found in API Gateway. CredentialsError: Missing credentials in
>   config

However, when I look in API Gateway I can see that the domain it’s referring to exists. So this leads me onto the next message which states about missing credentials. I’m assuming it’s expecting a certificate to be installed on my machine? If I’m right, how can I get this from within AWS Console? If I’m wrong, does anyone know where I should be trying next.

Comment: Hi, have you setup your aws [credentials](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials.md) in your workspace where you are running sls commands?.

Comment: would e easier if you pasted your serverless.yml over here.
Without being able to see anything, my best guess is that you haven't really done any configuration for Route53. Route53 is responsible for managing your HTTP domains and since it's billed separately from all other services (you're charged immediately when you buy a domain, rather than for the actual usage over a month), I reckon it has to be handled manually before you can deploy your template